# Until I do shopping or Until I am doing shopping?

Tags: grammar

e.g

> Until I do shopping, you can get a coffee.

Or

> Until I am doing shopping, you can get a coffee.

Please tell me which one is correct?

Comment: Thank you, why the 2nd one is wrong? They both are in continuous tense.

Comment: Do you mean _While I am doing the shopping, you can get a coffee_? (Only the second sentence is in the continuous aspect.)

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: Both are grammatical, but both are also unidiomatic. Normally, neither would be used. (It's very rare to combine *do* with *shop*.)

Comment: "Get a coffee while I do the shopping." / "Get a coffee while I finish the shopping."

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "do shopping". It's more idiomatic to say "go shopping"